# How to replace null values based on other column match in the same table

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Apologies if this is a basic question, but I'm just getting started using SQL and BigQuery.

I have a table with 2 specific unique identifiers used for different events as below:

```
+--------+----------+--------+
|  Type  | Instance | Userid |
+--------+----------+--------+
| event1 | abc123   | user1  |
| event1 | abc123   | user1  |
| event2 | abc123   | null   |
| event2 | def456   | null   |
| event1 | def456   | user2  |
+--------+----------+--------+
```

The information recorded depends on the event type, with event 1 recording both types of identification, and event 2 only recording 1 type (to save space). How would one go about using the instance identifier, which is recorded for both event types, as a lookup to replace the null values in userid with the corresponding user values: i.e. we know instance "abc123" is a product of user1, therefore any event (such as event2) with an instance "abc123" and a null value for userid should replace the null value with "user1". Resulting in this:

```
+--------+----------+--------+
|  Type  | Instance | Userid |
+--------+----------+--------+
| event1 | abc123   | user1  |
| event1 | abc123   | user1  |
| event2 | abc123   | user1  |
| event2 | def456   | user2  |
| event1 | def456   | user2  |
+--------+----------+--------+
```

I've looked into functions like `COALESCE`, and `IFNULL`, but I'm not sure they're supported with my version of BigQuery, and all the different flavours of `JOIN` seems to assume different tables (I'm using just the one in an isolated environment).

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  What do you want if there are multiple rows for the same user?

Comment: If you want to post a fixed-width code sample block, prefix each of its lines with four spaces `    `. This will automatically displayed as a code black by the Markdown, optionally applying syntaxic coloration if available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get one value by using window functions:

```
select type, instance,
       coalesce(userid, max(userid) over (partition by instance))
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer is undoubtedly the most optimal (and should be accepted!).

However - since you mentioned `JOIN`s, here is an example with joins for educational purposes.

Firstly I am splitting out all the distinct `Type`, `Instance` & `Userid` combinations from the table where userID is not null. And then joining this new dataset onto the original table only taking `Userid`'s from this newly created subset of data.

```
WITH
  userid_populated AS (
  SELECT
    distinct Type, Instance, Userid
  FROM
    t
  WHERE
    userid IS NOT NULL)
SELECT
  b.Type,
  b.Instance,
  a.Userid
FROM
  t AS a
LEFT JOIN
  userid_populated AS b
ON
  a.Type = b.Type
  AND a.Instance = b.Instance
```

Hope this is of interest.

Comment: It absolutely is thanks, any opportunity to learn and get better aquatinted with SQL :)